# How to start Python REPL quietly?

Tags: python, stdout, ipython, startup

Is there a way to startup python quietly, perhaps by setting some environment variable or supplying command line option?  Instead of seeing this:

```
wim@SDFA100461C:/tmp$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Sometimes I want this behaviour, straight to the prompt:

```
wim@SDFA100461C:/tmp$ python
>>>
```

I would also be interested in an answer for `ipython`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
C:\Users\Bartek>python -i -c ""
>>> print "I ♥ Python!"
I ♥ Python!
>>> exit()

C:\Users\Bartek>
```

The `-i` option is described as:

> -i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
>            if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x

So as long as you're on a terminal, it doesn't seem to have any caveats.

`ipython` has a straightforward `--no-banner` option:

```
C:\Users\Bartek>ipython --no-banner

In [1]: print "I <3 Python!"
I <3 Python!

In [2]: exit()

C:\Users\Bartek>
```

It doesn't seem to support Unicode though ;)

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.2 onwards you can use the `-q` flag:

```
$ python3 -q
>>>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-q